# AJAX and PHP login class aren't working nicely together. Invalid credentials still being logged in

Tags: php, ajax, class, authentication

I have a PHP login class that I wrote:

```php
include('../../datatypes/User.datatype.php');

$usher = new Authenticator;
$usher->checkCreds();
$usher->ensureHasAccess();

Class Authenticator {

    protected $user;

    protected function getCreds() {
        if (!isset($_POST['adminLogin']))
            echo('There was an error handling your request');
        else if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']))
            echo('You must enter a username and password');
        $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $password = md5(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

        $this->user = new User;
        $this->user->username = $username;
        $this->user->password = $password;
    }

    public function checkCreds() {
        $this->getCreds();
        if (empty($this->user->username) || empty($this->user->password))
            echo('There was an error processing your request');
        include('../../../dbconnect.php');
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;", $db_user, $db_password);
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT userID, userFName FROM Users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?');
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->user->username);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $this->user->password);
        $stmt->bindColumn(1, $tblUserID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindColumn(2, $userFName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
        if ($stmt->rowCount() != 1)
            echo "{\"result\" : false}";
        $this->user->tblUserID = $tblUserID;
        $this->user->firstName = $userFName;
        $status = true;
    }

    protected function createSessionID() {
        $seshID = mt_rand(99999, 1000000000);
        return $seshID;
    }

    protected function startSession() {
        if ($status === false)
            echo "{\"result\" : false}";
        echo "{\"result\" : true}";
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['id'] = $this->createSessionID();

        $secret = crypt($_SESSION['id']);
        $_SESSION['lastInsert'] = 0;
        $_SESSION['tblUserID'] = $this->user->tblUserID;
        $_SESSION['firstName'] = $this->user->firstName;
        $_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
        header('Location: ../../index.php?=admin');
    }

    public function ensureHasAccess() {
        $grantedAccess = $this->startSession();
        if ($grantedAccess === false)
            header('Location: ../../error/403.php');
        echo "{\"result\" : true}";
        session_start();
    }

}
```

Note: I'm usting MD5 for testing, otherwise uses bcrypt. Also, this works just fine without the AJAX, which looks like this:

```
$('#login_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    if (username == '' || password == '')
        $('span#errForm').fadeIn(200).text('You must enter a username and password');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/classes/login/Authenticator.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.result === false)
                $('span#errForm').fadeIn(200).text('Invalid username or password');
            else
                window.location = '/index.php?=admin';
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

To process this form:

```
    <div class="actionDiv">
        <span id="errForm"></span>
        <form id="login_form" action="./classes/login/Authenticator.php" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
            <p>username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></p>
            <p>password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="adminLogin" value="Log in" id="adminLogin" /></p>
        </form>
        <p><a id="cancelLogin" href="">Cancel</a></p>
    </div>
```

The problem is that when no form data is entered, or invalid form data is entered, a login still occurs. When I do use the correct login data, clicking the submit button does nothing, and I have to manually refresh the page. When no form data is entered, there's a message that says so, but refreshing the page just creates an empty session.

I tried using `error: function(data)` but nothing changes. The console doesn't display any errors, either. What am I missing here? Does the PHP being in a class have any effect on this?

Edit: In Chrome developer tools, under network, the status for Authenticator.php is 200 ok on both proper and improper logins.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return false in the following javascript line:

```
if (username == '' || password == '')
    $('span#errForm').fadeIn(200).text('You must enter a username and password');
```

This should be

```
if (username == '' || password == '')
{
    $('span#errForm').fadeIn(200).text('You must enter a username and password');
    return false;
}
```

Furthermore, in your php class, you could change the following:

```
if ($stmt->rowCount() != 1)
    echo "{\"result\" : false}";
```

to:

```
if ($stmt->rowCount() != 1)
    die "{\"result\" : false}";
```

Comment: What does changing it to 'die' do, exactly?

Comment: It will die and won't start the function `$usher->ensureHasAccess();`, which calls `startSession()`. In there, you always set `$_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;`. You could also try to return false in `if ($status === false)`.

Comment: Using `die` will stop the script from executing any further ie lines after `die` will not be executed and the script will be terminated.

Comment: die() ends the script execution while echo() prints something and the script contiues.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. You can append the json to die? Also, do I have to echo at the beginning of the PHP `{"result" : true}` ?